# Allow to send Javascript Code with Method Post in PHP

Tags: php, apache, post

I have a problem submitting a form from my app.

I need to send some JavaScript code from a form to a controller page. The code in html is like:

```
<form method="post" action="controller/mycontroller.php">
    <textarea name="code"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

If I send on `textarea` "Hello world" for example, the controller works fine, but if I try to send some `javascript` code like `alert(1);` I get a forbidden message from server.

Any solution for send `javascript` code to server as a string like filters or allowing something on the `.htaccess` file?

Thanks!

RE-Edit:
Test example: http://pruebas.intelectiva.biz/test/

Comment: apache doesn't care what you are sending

Comment: Why are you attempting to send client-side scripts to your server in the first place?

Comment: I need to change the functionality of my webapp but i don't want to modify the code and submit the app on the diferent markets. I load that code at the beggining on the application and that is launched on my aplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert at first the text of the textarea with javascript to replace the code like brakets into random letters that you will never use.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var code = $("#code").val();

        code = code.replace(/\(/g, "^)·(");
        code = code.replace(/\{/g, "=?¿¡12");
        code = code.replace(/\</g, "++ççcsacsa");

        $("#code").val(code);
        alert (code);

        $("#form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

And then, in the server side reconvert the text to your desired text:

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];
$code = str_replace('^)·(', '(', $code);
$code = str_replace('=?¿¡12', '{', $code);
$code = str_replace('++ççcsacsa', '<', $code);
echo '<script>'. $code . '</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't depends on what you are posting but i think it depends on WHERE you are posting, are you sure this `action="controller/mycontroller.php"` is correct?

try `action="http://www.mysite.com/controller/mycontroller.php"` instead

also post your `.htaccess` if you have one

and yeah, put your project folder and files to right permissions, if from shell:

```
sudo chmod 755 <filename>
```

Comment: I dont have .htaccess for now. But the path is correct. When I post normal strings that form works perfectly. But if I post some javascript code like alert(1), I get the forbidden message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a forbidden error then definitely it is a permissions fault.
It had happened to me earlier. Just right click on your web directory and make sure the permissions for the file "controller/mycontroller.php" for "other uses" is set to "read" if you're on ubuntu

can you please tell us which OS you're using?

(by the way, when you say action="controller/mycontroller.php" it means that the folder controller is in the same folder as the HTML form)

also to execute the javascript your php file should look like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>" . $_POST['code'] . "</script>";
?>
```

EDIT:
hey friend!
i tried your example on my server, it worked here's my app:

```
http://106.51.68.115/test/x.html
```

instead of submitting the form to another php file try submitting it to the same file:

```
<form method="post" action="controller/mycontroller.php">
    <textarea name="code"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
print "<script>".$_POST['code']."</script>";
}
?>
```

EDIT XYZ:
try this code, it doesn't involve PHP and i think it should work:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name = "x">
<textarea id="code"></textarea></form><button onclick="document.write('<script>'+document.x.code.value+'</script>');">send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using windows. But the server is a shared webserver, and I supose that is under Linux.

Comment: check my url @Enacefio i've used thecode you've provided for the html page and the code i've provided for the php page (by the way, the IP will be valid only for today)

Comment: @okok, the shell code you provided works only on unix environment, Enacefio uses windows

Comment: Wow, thanks for the example, look at my example: http://pruebas.intelectiva.biz/test/

Comment: yes, as i said, it says i dont have permission to access the folder, i can tell you how to enable permissions if you tell me which windows are you using

Comment: If you send "hello world" you woldn't have permision problems.

Comment: instead of submitting the form to another page try to submit the form to the same page and then use the php code i gave you - CHECK MY ANSWER EDIT

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've modified my previous example to send the form to itself.

Comment: can you tell what permissions are set on the file /test/index.php try to set all permissions to "allow", i had encountered the same problem on my apache server and i changed permissions and it worked. by the way, windows is reallllyyy bad for web development use Ubuntu, its free and easy to change permissions. I have windows but i also go ubuntu for web dev. purposes

Comment: index.php has : <?php
    echo "<script>" . $_POST['code'] . "</script>";
?>
<form method="post" action="">
 <textarea name="code"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

Comment: can you tell for which user is the permission 777

Comment: to change permissions in windows open cmd and type: cacls /p <username>:f (for full permissions). to know more type cacls /?

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/windows-change-access-permissions-from-the-command-line.html

Comment: I changed the permissions to 755, and on the apache log i get a 404 error. I'm going crazy! [21/May/2013:12:34:23 +0200] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://pruebas.intelectiva.biz/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"

Comment: try this code:
<?php echo "<script>" . $_GET['code'] . "</script>"; ?> <form> <textarea name="code"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="send" /> </form>

Comment: I don't think that isn't the problem.

Comment: try this code: <?php echo "<script>" . $_GET['code'] . "</script>"; ?> <form> <textarea name="code"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="send" /> </form> @Enacefio

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I dont want to execute the code on the page, I just want to send the code to another php to store it on a database or a file. :( I can't find the solution. I think that is a problem with mod_security from apache or something like this.

Comment: @Enacefio ok, i'll give you the code to store it in a database, but for that you'll have to tell me, whether you have MySQL installed in your server

Comment: tell me what fields you want in the table in your database i'll give you the code @Enacefio

Comment: A field for reference other table.

Comment: i couldn't understand... check this website for db interaction in php: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: I know how to interact with database, but that is not the problem. The problem is that when I try to submit code on a form, the server responses me with a forbidden code. And I dont know why! If I could recieve code as string on my php I will save it on a file or on a database but I can't recive it because the server forbiddes me to send javascript code on my form. That is the problem! You can try to send two strings on this form: http://pruebas.intelectiva.biz/test/ The allowed string: "Hello world" and the disallowed string: "alert(1);"